# Convert from long to Text

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I have the following method

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

public class IpConversion extends UDF{
    private Text result = new Text();
    static int power = 0;

    public Text evaluate(String input){
        if(input != null){
            long res = 0;
            String [] ipAddressInArray = input.split("\\.");

            for(int i=ipAddressInArray.length-1; i>= 0; i--){
                long ip = Integer.parseInt(ipAddressInArray[i]);
                res += ip * Math.pow(256, power);
                power += 1;
                //System.out.println(ipAddressInArray(i));        
            }

            return result;
        }
        //return null;
    } 
}
```

I'm trying to convert the variable `res` from `long` to `Text` (`org.apache.hadoop.io.Text`) but I don't know how to do that. I've tried to convert it from `long` `toString()` and then use the method `.set()` of the `Text` class but I had an error "cannot return void ".

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks.

Comment: Well, i could not see you are setting result field in anywhere in the evaluate method? This can cause the problem i think

Comment: If one of the answers helped you solve your problem, it would be nice if you could "accept" the answer so others can find the solution quickly.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.html#Text(java.lang.String)) is the documentation of your `Text` class. As you can see  you can instantiate a `Text` object with `Text myText = new Text(myString)`.

So in your case it could look something like this:

```
....
return new Text(""+res);
```

First it creates a String with `""+res` (append your long to an empty string) and then it instantiates a new `Text` object with that String `new Text("...."); and returns it right away.